# Removing the confidence interval on ggplot2 on plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot and I am trying to remove the confidence interval(the gray cast on the smooth line)for each on my line but it's not working. I used the code below:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=, y=)) + geom_smooth(aes(color="KHRC"),se = FALSE, span = 0.3)+
  geom_smooth(data=GO1,aes(color="GO1"))+
  geom_smooth(data=GO2,aes(color="GO2"))+
  geom_smooth(data=GO4,aes(color="GO4"))+
  geom_smooth(data=GO3,aes(color="GO3"))+
  geom_smooth(data=GO6,aes(color="GO6"))+
  scale_x_datetime(limits = c(ymd_hms("2016-11-05 09:00:00"), ymd_hms("2016-11-07 00:00:00")))+
  labs(color="ID")+
  ggtitle("x vs y ")
```

I need help with what code to use to remove the confidence interval.Also, I see no difference when I change the span, suggestions on that too will be great.Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Add `se = FALSE` to each of the `geom_smooth` functions

Comment: Or put all your data together and call geom_smooth once with `se = FALSE`.

Answer (score 6):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=, y=)) + geom_smooth(aes(color="KHRC"),se = FALSE, span = 0.3)+
  geom_smooth(data=GO1,aes(color="GO1"),se = FALSE,span = 0.3)+
  geom_smooth(data=GO2,aes(color="GO2"),se = FALSE,span = 0.3)+
  geom_smooth(data=GO4,aes(color="GO4"),se = FALSE,span = 0.3)+
  geom_smooth(data=GO3,aes(color="GO3"),se = FALSE,span = 0.3)+
  geom_smooth(data=GO6,aes(color="GO6"),se = FALSE,span = 0.3)+
  scale_x_datetime(limits = c(ymd_hms("2016-11-05 09:00:00"), ymd_hms("2016-11-07 00:00:00")))+
  labs(color="ID")+
  ggtitle("x vs y ")
```